# Why does thread interrupt sometimes not work?

Tags: java, android

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    renderThread = new Thread(() -> {
                        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                            try {
                                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                                canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
                                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    renderThread.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int width, int height, int format) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    renderThread.interrupt();
                    try {
                        renderThread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            Thread renderThread;
        });
    }
}
```

I want to draw something using SurfaceView in a thread.

I create a new render thread after the surface is created and terminate the render thread when surface is destroyed.

But sometimes `renderThread` does not terminate when surface is destroyed and the thread will go into a infinite loop.

`Thread.interrupted()` still return false after calling `renderThread.interrupt()`.

It looks like the `renderThread.interrupt()` doesn't work.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you touched  the case when calling interrupt doesn't set the interrupted flag.

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.

I will suggest you to check if your code (or code you depend) catch the InterruptedException somewhere to confirm or deny my suspicion.

btw. there is many other possibilities when interrupted flag could be cleared (by example calling #interrupted it self...) so i will suggest you to use something else in while check clause to prevent of losing control of it)

Comment: Thank you,The reason for this problem is that calling unlockCanvasAndPost() function blocks the thread like you said,This function is not designed to throw an InterruptedException but silently captured and handled all the exceptions,So it led to this inexplicable failure

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch `Exception`. Catch the exceptions you expect, and that you know how to deal with. Ptobably you are catching `InterruptedException`, which can be thrown instead of setting the interrupt flag in some circumstances